# Problem with infinite loop in slider using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried making jQuery slider, which will pause on current image for couple of seconds and then move images horizontally. Also, when slider presents the last image in collection, slider should slowly get back to first image, or when marginLeft attribute reaches value of -200vw(it decreases gradually for -100vw after every image). Most of the time slider works perfectly, but there are also moments when slider ignores my **if** and goes above -200vw(sometimes up to -3000vw), resulting in showing no images.  The only thing that I noticed in this situation is that this problem can occur after around 5-10 minutes spent on other browser tabs.

P.S I apologize for a lack of precise details, because these are the only thing I have noticed with this problem

**jQuery/Javascript**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let delay           = 5300;
  let currentSlide    = 1;
  let $carousel       = $('#carousel')
  let $slideContainer = $carousel.find('.slides');
  let $width          = 100;
  let $slides         = $slideContainer.find('.slide')

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $slideContainer.animate({
      'marginLeft': '-=' + $width + 'vw'
    }, 1000, function() {
      currentSlide++;
      var abc = $slideContainer.width();
      if (currentSlide == $slides.length) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $slideContainer.animate({
            'marginLeft': '+=' + ($width + 100) + 'vw'
          }, 1000, function() {
            currentSlide = 1;
            $slideContainer.css({
              'marginLeft': 0 + 'vw'
            })
          })
        }, (delay / 2.5))
      }
    })
  }, delay);
});
```

**HTML**

```HTML
<section id="carousel">
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="../javaskript/images/slider/gaming1.jpg" style="height:100vh" alt="Introduction image 2 - slider" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="../javaskript/images/slider/gaming2.jpg" style="height:100vh" alt="Introduction image 2 - slider">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="../javaskript/images/slider/scorn.jpg" style="height:100vh" alt="Introduction image 2 - slider">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#carousel {
  overflow    : hidden;
  white-space : nowrap;
  width       : 300vw;
  height      : 100vh;
  }
.slides {
  display : flex;
  width   : 300vw;
  margin  : 0;
  padding : 0;
  }
.slide {
  width    : 100vw;
  overflow : hidden;
  }
```

Comment: This is what all browsers do when a page is no longer in the foreground, all actions or processes related to that page are stopped

Comment: Thank you @MisterJojo for reply. If that problem can`t be changed, should I keep this slider on my website?

Comment: two solutions: 1) use a css animation, 2) base your synchronization based on the system clock and not on a delay.